# File API - works with cURL but fails with AJAX and Postman

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl, gotenberg

I am running `gotenberg` as my document to PDF conversion `API` and it is working with `cURL`.

The `cURL` command looks like this

```
curl --request POST --url http://example.com  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --form files=@file.docx > result.pdf
```

The `API` works only with `cURL`, When i try hitting the same `API` with `Postman` or `AJAX` i get a response but on saving the details or by previewing the response using `Postman` i get an empty PDF file.

My `AJAX` request looks like this

```
  var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://convertionapi.com",
        "method": "POST",
        "processData": false,
        "contentType": false,
        "data": form,
        success: function(data){
            console.log("Success", data);
            s3.upload({
                Key: "files/test.pdf",
                Body: data,
                ContentType: 'application/pdf',
                ACL: 'public-read',
            },function(err, data) {...}
    },
    error: function(err) { 
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
}
```

Can anyone throw some light as to what is happening with my request?

I get the below headers with my response but the created files are empty

[image]

Comment: What are you getting in the console.log, when you write "Success" + data?

Comment: I am getting like this https://imgur.com/a/hfPQdWB

Comment: Then, it seems that you are getting correctly the PDF from the ajax request. Now what you need to do with that information? Download it?

Comment: I am trying to save the PDF to S3 and a PDF is being created on S3, but the entire PDF is just one empty file, by empty file i mean there is no content just plain A4 sheets :/

Comment: I have no idea of what S3 is. Just in case, are you able to see the size of the file created in S3? Is it 51563 bytes? Or it is 0bytes?

Comment: Also what I see it is different is that in the CURL you have set the Content-Type header, try to set it in your ajax request. Also, I am not sure if you are passing correctly the data in the variable "form"

Comment: Size is correct and I am able to see some part of the content in the raw part of Postman but the files are just blank. It's amazon S3. The file is like this https://imgur.com/a/5sIvlNJ

Comment: Set that header as well. Still the same.

Comment: Then it seems that you are not doing it well the request. Try to correct it based on what I have just said in previously comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184078/discussion-between-brank-victoria-and-nithin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to handle `blob` response and thus my `AJAX` call must have looked like this.

```
var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://convertionapi.com",
        "method": "POST",
        "processData": false,
        "contentType": false,
        "data": form,
        "xhr": function(){
               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               xhr.responseType= 'blob'
               return xhr;
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log("Success", data);
            s3.upload({
                Key: "files/test.pdf",
                Body: data,
                ContentType: 'application/pdf',
                ACL: 'public-read',
            },function(err, data) {...}
    },
    error: function(err) { 
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
}
```